# PHP changed array while iterating

Tags: php, arrays

I stumbled with interesting behaviour of php script.

```
$source = array (
    "1" =>
        array (
            'eft' => '1025',
            'flights' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'flightNumber' => '733',
                            'rbd' => 'E',
                        ),
                    1 =>
                        array (
                            'flightNumber' => '1429',
                            'rbd' => 'E',
                        ),
                    2 =>
                        array (
                            'flightNumber' => '1790',
                            'rbd' => 'E',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);

var_dump($source[1]['flights'][0]['flightNumber']);
var_dump($source[1]['flights'][1]['flightNumber']);
var_dump($source[1]['flights'][2]['flightNumber']);

foreach ([1] as $segmentFlightRef) {
    $segFlights = $source;
    $i = 1;
    $j = 0;

    foreach ([1] as $referencingDetail) {

        foreach ($segFlights[$i]['flights'] as &$flight) {
            $flight['rbd'] = 'E';
            $flight['fareName'] = 'E';
            $j++;
        }

        foreach ($segFlights[$i]['flights'] as $flight) {
            if ($flight['flightNumber'] != '733') {
                continue 3;
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }

}

var_dump($segFlights[1]['flights'][0]['flightNumber']);
var_dump($segFlights[1]['flights'][1]['flightNumber']);
var_dump($segFlights[1]['flights'][2]['flightNumber']);
```

And script outputs:

```
test_array_iteration.php:76: string(3) "733"
test_array_iteration.php:77: string(4) "1429"
test_array_iteration.php:78: string(4) "1790"
test_array_iteration.php:104: string(3) "733"
test_array_iteration.php:105: string(4) "1429"
test_array_iteration.php:106: string(4) "1429" << there must be "1790"
```

If I remove first iterator by `as &$flight`, the array is not modified. And if I add `&` to second iterator. It seems that php incorrectly iterates throw array when it is already iterated by reference.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "It seems that php incorrectly iterates throw array when it is already iterated by reference." --- it works as expected: you created a reference, so whatever value is passed there is being written to the destination value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unset a reference variable, otherwise the second loop overwrites the reference value (which refers to the last item of an array):

```
    foreach ($segFlights[$i]['flights'] as &$flight) {
        $flight['rbd'] = 'E';
        $flight['fareName'] = 'E';
        $j++;
    }

    unset($flight); // <-- !!!!!!!

    foreach ($segFlights[$i]['flights'] as $flight) {
        if ($flight['flightNumber'] != '733') {
            continue 3;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you may use different names as a `foreach` item recipient.